# i got this error 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

when i am update my form, i got this error
500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception

executeEdit

```
public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->form = new ContactForm();

    $this->rs = Doctrine::getTable('login')-> find($request->getParameter('id'));

    $id=$request->getParameter('id');
    $unm=$this->rs['username'];
    $msg=$this->rs['message'];
    $em=$this->rs['email'];
    $sub=$this->rs['subject'];
    $this->form->setDefault('id', $id);
    $this->form->setDefault('username', $unm);
    $this->form->setDefault('message', $msg);
    $this->form->setDefault('email', $em);
    $this->form->setDefault('subject', $sub);
    //$this->forward404Unless($this->rs);   


    if ($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('contact'), $request->getFiles('contact'));

        if ($this->form->isValid())
        {
            $name="'".$this->form->getValue('username')."'";
            $message="'".$this->form->getValue('message')."'";
            $email="'".$this->form->getValue('email')."'";
            $sub="'".$this->form->getValue('subject')."'";
            $id=$this->form->getValue('id');

            $file = $this->form->getValue('doc');
            $filename = sha1($unm).'_'.sha1($file->getOriginalName());
            $extension = $file->getExtension($file->getOriginalExtension());
            $path=sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/'.$filename.$extension;
            $qs= Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->update('login l')
                ->set('l.username', $name)
                ->set('l.message', $message)
                ->set('l.email', $email)
                ->set('l.subject', $sub)
                ->set('l.doc', $path)
                ->where('l.id=?',$id)
                ->execute();
                $this->redirect('user/show?id=' . $id);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my edit action code. so whats the exaclty error. and what is my mistake
and what can i do to solve this error?
please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [error on update form , got error like Doctrine\_Connection\_Mysql\_Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900097/error-on-update-form-got-error-like-doctrine-connection-mysql-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you add quotes to the values you are saving? Doctrine will handle this for you. Try removing this part:

```
$name="'".$this->form->getValue('username')."'";
$message="'".$this->form->getValue('message')."'";
$email="'".$this->form->getValue('email')."'";
$sub="'".$this->form->getValue('subject')."'";
```

You're not utilising the power of Doctrine and forms fully.

E.g. instead of this:

```
$this->form = new ContactForm();

$this->rs = Doctrine::getTable('login')-> find($request->getParameter('id'));

$id=$request->getParameter('id');
$unm=$this->rs['username'];
$msg=$this->rs['message'];
$em=$this->rs['email'];
$sub=$this->rs['subject'];
$this->form->setDefault('id', $id);
$this->form->setDefault('username', $unm);
$this->form->setDefault('message', $msg);
$this->form->setDefault('email', $em);
$this->form->setDefault('subject', $sub);
```

You could use this:

```
$this->rs =  Doctrine_Core::getTable('login')-> find($request->getParameter('id'));
$this->form = new ContactForm($this->rs);
```

You only have to "connect" your form to a proper model by adding this function:

```
public function getModelName()
{
    return 'login';
}
```

You could then use the `save` method on the form so it automatically saves your object without having to create the update query.

Also have a look at the `sfValidatorFile` as it will automatically create a unique filename for you.

Comment: thanks but got this error.. 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException
Unknown record property / related component "_csrf_token" on "login"

Comment: Add `$form->renderHiddenFields()` to the template or `$this->disableLocalCSRFProtection()` to the `configure` method of your form class. (the first one is a much better solution). Also read the Sf 1.4. documentation about CSRF protection in forms.